# Elixir: String Force encode UTF-8

Tags: ruby, encoding, elixir

I have a gem in ruby that does translations using google API and I am "translating" it to Elixir.

For example, I get from API some like this:
[api-data](https://translate.google.com/translate_a/single?client=p&sl=en&tl=pt-CN&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&dt=t&dt=rm&q=Hello,)

And in Ruby today I do this:

```
  encoded = rawdata.force_encoding("UTF-8")
```

I would like to know if there is a way to "force_encode" (like Ruby does) but with Elixir?

**UPDATE SOLUTION**

I reached a solution based in your answers guys thanks a lot!

As Elixir handle it as binaries then that is the trick: I get the response body: `body |> IO.iodata_to_binary ...`

```
defmodule Request do
  alias Extract
  use HTTPotion.Base

  def process_url(url) do
    "https://translate.google.com/translate_a/" <> url
  end

  def process_response_body(body) do
    body |> IO.iodata_to_binary |> Extract.extract
  end
end
```

[Here is entire code](https://github.com/CristianOliveiraDaRosa/elixfregle)

Comment: Elixir strings (which are more properly called binaries) are UTF-8 by default.  Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: You are right. I saw that in documentation. The problem is I receive a file in this URL (that I've posted) and this file has some strange encoding so when I parse it for a text I get things like "OlÃ¡". I've solved whit ruby by `force_encoding`.  Any thought?

Comment: Hmm. I don't know where you're getting that file from but according to UChardet (on my Linux box) the encoding is TIS-620. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thai_Industrial_Standard_620-2533  I'd look for some sort of utility to convert that to UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks @OnorioCatenacci I found a solution!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use force encoding in Ruby when the data is tagged as binary but really is UTF-8. In Elixir, they are both at the same time, because all strings are binaries, we don't tag them in anyway. In other words, you shouldn't need to *force encoding*.

However, if the data is not in UTF-8, then you need to find a way to convert it to UTF-8 in the first place.

Comment: Thanks @JoséValim. I found a solution based in your answer! I updated the post with.